# Drawing custom data-based shapes with mapbox

Tags: ios, mapbox-gl

I have been tasked with drawing complex custom shape using mapbox-gl iOS library. The backend created using mapbox-gl-native codebase (as well as custom iOS SDK) provides the data on where the shapes should be drawn and what data should be displayed.

My initial thoughts are on implementing the drawing in mbgl-core library where the library fetches the style and parses out the parameters of layers. However I was unable to find *any* documentation on this topic.

So my questions are where should I be looking to write the code that does the drawing (presumably in C++ using OpenGL) and where is the code that parses the fetched style and layer parameters?

Comment: For the style portion of your question, see https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/tree/master/src/mbgl/style.   May need to switch away from `master` to latest iOS release.